# gstreamer's udpsink stops streaming after sending ~1000 packets

Tags: udp, gstreamer

I'm trying to stream my Raspberry Pi camera with gstreamer. This is my pipeline:

```
raspivid --nopreview -ih -hf -vf --width 800 --height 600 --framerate 20 --bitrate 2000000 --profile main --timeout 0 -g 4 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -vvv fdsrc do-timestamp=true \
 ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! clockoverlay time-format="%A | %d %B %Y | %H:%M:%S" ! omxh264enc target-bitrate=2000000 control-rate=1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=targethost port=8004 sync=false
```

And it works... well almost. I can receive stream on my target host for a second or so, then it stops. Gstreamer doesn't output any errors, doesn't quit, it just stops sending out UDP packets.

I installed `iptraf` on my Pi and I can see that UDP packet sending stops after about ~1000 packets. It might stop at ~800 packets, or ~1500 packets, it's around these numbers.

Now interesting thing is that SOMETIMES it works longer, like for a few hours. But sometimes it just stops almost instantly. I'm observing this for about two days now, and it might be that it works better at night, maybe because the stream is pitch black then, so with better compression, it has less packets to send? I don't know. What can stop packet sending without any error like that? Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

**Added #1:**
Also in case it's an infrastructure issue, Pi is connected with local network through its wi-fi interface, and it's actually connected to the wi-fi extender. So it's not a very clean setup, but it seems to work at night, at least judging from the last two days, but even if there would be some bandwidth bottleneck, could it stop UDP stream like that? It doesn't make sense to me.

**Added #2:**

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 --version
gst-launch-1.0 version 1.14.4
GStreamer 1.14.4
```

**Added #3:**

I run this with `GST_DEBUG=3`. when it stops it doesn't show anything new, just any new messages stop appearing.

Here is full output until stream dies without any further message: https://pastebin.com/raw/kTfbCW37 (these warnings happen even if stream works without a problem for a long time in some configurations described below).

I discovered also that bandwidth is not a problem. I measured it with `iperf` and the stream is using only about 1/10th of available bandwidth at most.

I also discovered that if I'll increase the resolution to `--width 1920 --height 1080` then stream seems to work longer... (it stopped at one point at night). So there is something very strange going on. Any ideas what may it be or what else can I do to figure out what is going on?

**Added #4:**
I installed `pv` and put it between `raspivid` and `gstreamer`. It turns out that it might not be an issue with gstreamer in the end, because it looks like the stream from raspivid just stops at one point. Once it stopped at 1.99GiB of data sent (this made me think that's related to old, known 2GB limit of raspivid), but second time it stopped at 775MiB of data sent.

Comment: Do you see something useful when adding the verbosity of gstreamer higher (e.g. GST_DEBUG=3)? And if you skip the h264 decoding, adding and encoding step, does it work well?

Comment: What's the pipeline to receive that stream?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar scenario on some other "embedded" device so I will share empirical knowledge gained back then.

In my case, I succeeded to make a stable stream with following approach:

- add [queue](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-queue.html) element before `udpsink`. `queue` will "create a new thread on the source pad to decouple the processing on sink and source pad" so, in theory, it should bring benefit if CPU has multiple cores. In my case `queue` "buffering" was higher then default:

  ```
  ... ! queue max-size-time=5000000000 max-size-buffers=10000000 max-size-bytes=50000000 ! udpsink ...
  ```
- increase `buffer-size` property of `udpsink` element. For example,

  ```
  ... ! updsink buffer-size=50000000 ...
  ```

should allow the kernel to buffer more packets when the udpsink cannot process packets fast enough.

In my case, above settings stabilized stream and eased up infrastructure bottlenecks.

And, as @vermeate suggested, additional debugging is always helpful: set GST_DEBUG level to some higher value, try to decrease `raspivid` framerate, bitrate.. and observe behaviour.

Comment: Unfortunately both these settings didn't help, but it looks like for some weird reason increasing the resolution of the camera made stream work longer. I'm completely baffled right now.

Comment: @ŁukaszZaroda I cannot explain that too :). However, there are 2 approaches to try: 1. to create linux bash script that will run your pipeline, somehow detect if it dies and restart it. 2. to try [rpicamsrc](https://github.com/thaytan/gst-rpicamsrc) Gstreamer plugin that needs to be built from source on your raspi.